# Archiva with LDAP - Bean not Found

Tags: ldap, archiva, ldap-client

I did the changes described in http://archiva.apache.org/redback/integration/ldap.html but now our Archiva 1.3.5. server doesn't start and upgrading to 1.3.6 leaves me with the same error message which states that the beans now referenced in the applicationContext.xml are not known:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class 
[org.apache.archiva.redback.common.ldap.user.LdapUserMapper] for bean with name 'ldapUserMapper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.archiva.redback.common.ldap.user.LdapUserMapper
```

P.S.: Ok I try to migrate to 1.4-M4 now, am I doing this correctly?

**unpack zip of 1.4-M4**

**copy applicationContext.xml (P.S.: I did a manual diff and merge at the end)**

```
cp ./1.3.6/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml ./1.4-M4/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
```

**move data**

```
mv 1.3.6/data 1.4-M4
```

**copy security.properties**

```
 cp ./1.3.6/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/maven/archiva/security.properties  1.4-M4/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/archiva/redback-security.properties
```

P.P.S.: Unfortunately, I have not been successfull with the migration. Do I have to do something with the data folder as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is related to last 1.4.x serie.

You must try last 1.4-M4

Comment: Ah thank you very much this was written nowhere! Is M4 stable enough for a productive environment?

Comment: it's used here https://archiva-repository.apache.org/archiva/index.html?request_lang=en  and looks stable :-)